# Bottom-up piecewise linear segmentation in R

Tags: r, segment

I'm working on Time Series data and want to create linear datapoint segments. For this purpose, I am utilizing the `dpseg` package. I need to go through base piecewise linear segmentation for the changed and standardized logreturn time series which is running fine yet How might I use it with the accompanying mean square error resistance `levels: 0.04, 0.1, or 0.25` (the mean square error thresholds)? Thanks for any assistance.

Data Sample:

```
structure(c(-0.0224237347306389, 0.0552428831483329, 0.0089149860098523, 
0.000242153753333696, 0.0400766972095106, 0.0540056569733416, 
-0.0097133925448869, -0.0225316247556133, 0.0362342279271157, 
-0.0158864596459622, 0.0206608261062584, -0.0015722087661576, 
0.0779486254504143, -0.00374023293747783, -0.012359870058452, 
0.028006859026048, 0.00154109798116941, -0.0261858520889184, 
-0.00534578864371404, 0.00697949639207707, -0.0149347433694249, 
-0.030353104266597, 0.00811974472683552, -0.00922930663026555, 
0.027982099807554, 0.0360111922329729, 0.0517619929380189, -0.00435707175039468, 
0.0155903768946679, -0.0258802742380055, 0.00451853214743281, 
-0.00340354827553035, 0.00869358075090787, -0.0148452797462628, 
0.0487649643513262, 0.0170999810409143, 0.0100535131234789, 0.00703679062864282, 
0.0248303851845453, -0.0279896725224074, 0.0320201681555687, 
0.0114676420366351, -0.0178189274238392, 0.00945781010216429, 
-0.0418535654221781, 0.00418855431797205, -0.0214020875157637, 
0.0460919385806058, -0.045900325869507, 0.000897679382109828), tsp = c(2018, 
2018.13424657534, 365), class = "ts")
```

Code:

```
# Transform the time series to log-returns
log_returns <- diff(log(ts_data))

# Calculate the variance and mean of log-returns
log_returns_mean <- mean(log_returns) # 0.000843043
log_returns_var <- var(log_returns) # 0.001440317

# Normalize the log-returns to z-score
z_score <- (log_returns - log_returns_mean) / sqrt(log_returns_var)
summary(z_score)

Segmentation:

type <- "var"  # use mean square error scoring
jumps <- FALSE # allow discrete jumps between segments?
P <- 1e-4      # break-point penalty, use higher P for longer segments

# get example data `z_score`
x <- seq_along(z_score)
y <- z_score

# Create a dpseg object
segsments <- dpseg(x = x, y = y, jumps = jumps, P = P, type = type)

print(segments)
```